# FASTAPI - Pydantic : TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I looking for and API. I have chosen to do it with FastAPI and Pydantic.
So I tried this :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

# Routes
@app.get("/")
async def home():
    return {"status" : 200, "message" : "Welcome home."}

if __name__ == "__main__" : 
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=XXXX)
```

and i get :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI #, Form, Request
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/fastapi/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .applications import FastAPI
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fastapi import routing
  File "../python3.6/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fastapi import params
  File "../python3.6/site-packages/fastapi/params.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo
  File "pydantic/__init__.py", line 2, in init pydantic.__init__
  File "pydantic/dataclasses.py", line 4, in init pydantic.dataclasses
    import types
  File "pydantic/error_wrappers.py", line 4, in init pydantic.error_wrappers
  File "pydantic/json.py", line 20, in init pydantic.json
  File "pydantic/types.py", line 283, in init pydantic.types
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

Can you help me to resolve it ? Can't find a solution...

Comment: Have you consider using a more recent version of python?

Comment: Well, I can't get a more recent version of python. I have to handle this with **python 3.6.4**

Comment: I think you forgot to add the "import uvicorn" in your example. I run you code with python 3.8.5 and worked just fine.

Comment: I also forget to put "import uvicorn" in my post above.

I tried with and without importing uvicorn, there is still the same problem. 
This problem seems to refer to pydantic instead of uvicorn and fastapi

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you defining `app`. Try including the following after you import `FastAPI` but before your do your decoration:

`app = FastAPI()`

Comment: Thank for your answer, I forget to put it into my post above. There is already an app defined. I making an edit